# E-mail Queued sending using AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm facing the issue of occasional emails being queued when sending through SES. This can be seen in the dynamodb. what might be the possible way and how to avoid this ?

Comment: Queued as it never sent, or queued before being sent? Are you near any rate or volume limits? Could it be related to the destination mail server not being available? This page says SES doesn't queue emails. Suggest you edit your question to give much more detail if you would like useful help :) https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/what-happens-when-you-reach-your-sending-limits/

Comment: Hello Tim, our case is queued before being sent. no, we are not in near any rate or volume limits. even not a problem with related to the destination mail server not being available. still, in some mails, we did face the issue ? can you pl explain a bit what might be the possible issue .thanks??

Comment: I don't have detailed knowledge of that service. SES must give some kind of logging or metrics, look into that. Otherwise I suggest you pay for AWS support for a month, their support is excellent.